# SharePoint 2007 Custom List Form No Item Exists

Tags: list, 2007, custom, form

Background:

- Created a blank aspx page in a folder called SitePages.
- Attached a master page.
- Inserted a Custom List Form (EDIT)
- Rearranged and styled the form with HTML/CSS
- I have about 9 such forms for the same List. Each user has contribute rights to the List, but is given different permissions on each of the 9 pages based on their group. Each form contains different fields shown to the user that they can edit.

I tested about 30 items. Out of the first 15 items, two had the following error. The last 15 all have this error. The error happens to all 9 forms on that particular item , whether it is an edit form or display form.

The item does exist.. without a doubt. It is hyperlinked from a custom page, but the url is generated correctly. Half the items do work after all. I checked the list itself and each ID number. They all exist.

Thanks for any help,

### Server Error in '/' Application.

No item exists at mysite/ROMs/SitePages/RomRequestApproval.aspx?Source=mysite/ROMs/default.aspx&ID=22.  It may have been deleted or renamed by another user. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: No item exists at mysite/ROMs/SitePages/RomRequestApproval.aspx?Source=mysite/ROMs/default.aspx&ID=22.  It may have been deleted or renamed by another user.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[SPException: No item exists at mysite/ROMs/SitePages/RomRequestApproval.aspx?Source=mysite/ROMs/default.aspx&ID=22.  It may have been deleted or renamed by another user.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.get_Item() +2005
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.get_ListItemDisplayName() +119
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPContentMapProvider.GetItemTitle(SPContext spContext, Int32 idItem) +148
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPContentMapProvider.CreateItemNode(SPContext spContext, SPWeb web, SPList list, Int32 idItem, String urlItem, String strTitle) +185
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPContentMapProvider.CreateContextNode(SPContext spContext, Boolean bIncludeForm) +2137
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPContentMapProvider.FindSiteMapNode(HttpContext context) +175
   System.Web.SiteMapProvider.get_CurrentNode() +52
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapPath.CreateControlHierarchy() +77
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapPath.CreateChildControls() +41
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +61
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3394

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

Any custom list forms must be kept in the folder for the list it belongs to. SharePoint 2007 does some sort of synchronization with the forms for the list to be sure the correct version is being used. This doesn't happen if the custom list form is not in that folder.

I moved all the forms from SitePages to the relevant folder and everything started working correctly. No issues since.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ID. ID is a reserved word in SharePoint.